# Looping through dataframes in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have about 21 dataframes that all need the same cleaning applied to them, I was hoping that instead of writing out 21 versions of the same code, that I could loop through them.

I imagined it would work something like this, where I would create a vector with the names of each dataframe and then loop through them all (note that all the dataframes have the exact same layout):

```
countries <- c("italy","france","spain"...)

for (y in 1:21){
  countries[y]$iso2_r <-
    countrycode(countries[y]$reporter, "country.name", "iso2c")
  countries[y]$iso2_p <-
    countrycode(countries[y]$partner, "country.name", "iso2c")
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the sample data frame for Italy, France, Spain with ```dput(head(df, n))``` where ```df``` is the data frame and ```n``` is the first n rows. You can give n=5 for example.

Comment: It's much easier in this situation to have all your data frames in a list rather than as separate entities in your global environment. That way you can iterate through the list very easily. As it stands you would have to use `df <- get(countries[y])` as the first line inside your loop, then work on `df`, then use `assign(countries[y], df)` at the end of each loop to rewrite the result to each data frame.

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron this helped me solve my problem. However I'd like to have a look into using lists as suggested! Do you have a link to any resources about putting dataframes into lists I've had a look online but I think I'm barking up the wrong tree. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try to adapt the following code to your needs:

```
library(tidyverse)

createdf <- function()  data.frame(name1 = runif(10), name2 = rnorm(10))

# Generate a list of 21 structurally-similar dataframes
dfs <- map(1:21,~ createdf()) %>% 
  set_names(LETTERS[1:21]) 

# Creates a thrird column, name3, in each dataframe, by summing name1+name2
dfs %>% 
  map(~ mutate(.x, name3 = name1+name2))
```